# Docker Desktop using 7GB memory while containers use no more than 250MB

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I have set up docker desktop for my local development. I have 3 containers running which, according to the charts, is currently using 200MB.

[image]

However in task manager, docker desktop is is using close to 7GB.

[image]

I have config the .wslconfig to contain:

```
[wsl2]
memory=1GB
processors=2
```

The containers I have contain a ton of schedule tasks throughout the day, so I don't want pause docker. Is there a config or setting I am missing to restrict the memory usage of docker desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of docker desktop you are using but  I found an issue on  [github](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12877) . It seems to have a similar problem to yours where configuring .wslconfig didnt limit memory usage. from the answers i read, it seemed that switching from wsl to hyper-v seemed to solve the issue, Additionally, shutting down WSL with `wsl.exe --shutdown` and then turning it back on with `wsl.exe` seemed to help others as well.